# Where does Docker know where to pull the .sh scripts from when building a Dockerfile?

Tags: github, docker, docker-compose

So here is a Dockerfile.  https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/~/dockerfile/

I am trying to use this in my Docker-Compose like so:

```
postgres:

  restart: always

  image: kartoza/postgis:9.4-2.1

  ports:

    - "5432:5432"
```

My question is, if you go back to that link and look at the Dockerfile, at the very bottom it is running start_postgres.sh and some other sh scripts.  How does docker know where to pull those sh scripts from?  I know there is a Kartoza/postgis github repo that has the scripts, but nowhere in the Dockerfile or my docker-compose is there any step to pull or point to the GitHub repo so I am totally confused where these scripts are pulled from when I run my docker-compose.

volumes:

```
- pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dockerfile` on Dockerhub is just for documentation purposes, the complete github repo is used to build the image, hence the scripts are available through Docker's [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

```
$ docker build https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis
```

Only using the linked `Dockerfile` will result in a build error.

Edit: To clarify, Docker Hub is an image repository. Built images are either uploaded or built by Docker Hub from a provided github repository. Other users can then simply download (pull) those images.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding some fundamentals of Docker.  So in my docker-compose above, what exactly is 'image' pulling if not just the Dockerfile from Docker Hub?  When I do a docker-compose build and then up, it builds with no issue and postgres is running.

Comment: It pulls the complete image from Docker Hub. Read up on [image](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/image) and [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/build) instructions in the docker-compose docs. `build` is used if you want to extend an existing image, `image` if you just want to use an already built image.

Comment: So.. in my Docker-Compose above, image: kartoza/postgis is an instruction to pull that image, which was already built using the GitHub repository with all the .sh scripts (among other things)?